# Using keras fit_generator to output sample_weights

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to output a tuple from keras model fit_generator. The output tuple should look like

```
(inputs, targets, sample_weights)
```

Size of inputs, targets, and sample weights numpy arrays is (64, 256, 256, 1). But value error is thrown no matter if I comile model with sample_weight_mode="temporal" or None. I couldn't find any straightforward examples. Can anybody help?

Comment: What do you mean by " trying to output a tuple from keras model fit_generator"? Do you want the generator you pass to `fit_generator` have such outputs?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry for not being precise.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the code (only the related part) and the error traceback?